# Repeated same-cylinder ignition coil failure 2014 Corolla

Tags: ignition-coil

My engine on my 2014 Corolla started to sputter and I took it to a mechanic who replaced the #2 ignition coil and all the spark plugs. A week later the engine started to act up again, but only after it had been running for a while 15-20 minutes on hot summer days. If I left it for a few hours it would run fine again initially for another 15-20 minutes. I had the coil replaced again but the problem started to re-occur a few days later.

OBD shows cylinder 2 misfire (and at some point also showed an air/fuel ratio mismatch, I assume from unburnt fuel from the misfire).

What could be the possible issue and what can I do to diagnose the problem myself?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I'm wondering if there's a grounding problem. I wouldn't know how to test it, but you could just try removing the coil and reinstalling it straight away to see if the problem temporarily goes away. Just thinking outloud.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 add a wire from the coil fixing point to a known good ground point...

Comment: Swap the coil on cylinder 2 with one of the other coils and see if the fault stays with cylinder 2.  Maybe you have a bad connector on bad harness, or a bad ECU or ignition amplifier if there is one.

Comment: @SolarMike - Good point. Just disconnecting and reconnecting from the wiring harness would also prove what I was wondering.

Comment: Hmm, I'm pretty sure I can already rule out the ignition coil itself, given that it has been replaced twice already. As for grounding, it's strange that a grounding problem would occur only after running for some time, but I'll try it.